# Get segments of datetime from one mayor datetime event if overlap with a coverage datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have a mayor event with a start and end datetimes:

```
mayor_event = {"start": '20/06/2019 15:31', end: '24/06/2019 10:45'}
```

And i need to compare it with intervals of coverage and get only the segments of time of availability:

```
coverage = {
  "mon_start": "9:00",
  "mon_end": "18:00",
  "tus_start": "9:00",
  "tus_end": "18:00",
  "wed_start": "9:00",
  "wed_end": "18:00",
  "thu_start": "9:00",
  "thu_end": "18:00",
  "fri_start": "8:00",
  "fri_end": "15:00"
}
```

from this comparison i need to get:

```
available_on = {
  1: ['20/06/2019 15:31', '20/06/2019 18:00'], //thursday
  2: ['21/06/2019 8:00', '21/06/2019 15:00'], //friday
  3: ['24/06/2019 9:00', '24/06/2019 10:45']  //monday
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You have an event starting at 15:31 on one day and ending 4 days later at 10:45. What does "coverage" mean during that time?

Comment: @JackFleeting the site of the event have only a few available times of access, so you have those intervals to act on the event.  I need to get the intervals of time datetime where was available the site while the event was active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is to create the entires in your result list for the events that span more than one day. I do this below using function `split_periods`. The availability is then calculated on the split records in `map_availability_of_start_day`.

```
def split_periods(df, start_col, end_col):
    """split off the perios which span multiple days"""
    df= pd.DataFrame(df, copy=True)
    repeat= True
    while repeat:
        multiday_indexer= truncate_to_date(df[start_col] + pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='D')) < df[end_col]
        new_records= pd.DataFrame(df[multiday_indexer], copy=True)
        new_records[start_col]= truncate_to_date(new_records[start_col] + pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='D'))
        # now fix the end col of the split record
        df.loc[multiday_indexer, end_col]= truncate_to_date(df[start_col] + pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='D'))
        # concatenate the two datasets
        df= pd.concat([df, new_records], axis='index', ignore_index=True)
        repeat= multiday_indexer.any()
    return df

def truncate_to_date(series):
    """returns a series with datetime64 where the time is truncated to 00:00:00"""
    return series.dt.date.astype('datetime64')

def map_availability_of_start_day(df, start_mapping, end_mapping):
    """split off the perios which span multiple days"""
    # handle all lines that span only one day and are not filled yet
    ser_weekday=         df['start'].dt.weekday
    ser_available_start= truncate_to_date(df['start']) + ser_weekday.map(start_mapping)
    ser_available_end=   truncate_to_date(df['start']) + ser_weekday.map(end_mapping)
    df['start']=         df['start'].where(df['start'] >= ser_available_start, ser_available_start)
    df['end']=           df['end'].where(df['end']     <= ser_available_end, ser_available_end)
    return df
```

Function `map_availability_of_start_day` takes a prepared dataframe to work on and two series objects with the start and end time of the coverage of a day (day represented as the number `Series.dt.weekday` returns --> 0=Monday, ... 6=Sunday). The time is stored as timedelta. You can get the data with this code (note the 'negative' working hours from 01:00 to 00:00 for sat and sun, which make filtering out these days quite easy later):

```
df_cov= pd.DataFrame({
        'weekday': list(range(7)),
        'start': ['1900-01-01 09:00', '1900-01-01 09:00', '1900-01-01 09:00', '1900-01-01 09:00', '1900-01-01 08:00', '1900-01-01 01:00', '1900-01-01 01:00'],
        'end':   ['1900-01-01 18:00', '1900-01-01 18:00', '1900-01-01 18:00', '1900-01-01 18:00', '1900-01-01 15:00', '1900-01-01 00:00', '1900-01-01 00:00']
    })
df_cov['start']= df_cov['start'].astype('datetime64')
df_cov['end']=   df_cov['end'].astype('datetime64')
df_cov['start_delta']= df_cov['start'] - truncate_to_date(df_cov['start'])
df_cov['end_delta']= df_cov['end'] - truncate_to_date(df_cov['end'])
df_cov.set_index('weekday', inplace=True)
```

Preparing the data and testing with it:

```
# create your testdata with the column type set to datetime 
# (I only fixed the end date which was 2015 in the original)
events= pd.DataFrame({
        'start': ['20/06/2019 15:31'], 
        'end':   ['24/06/2019 10:45']})
events['start']= pd.to_datetime(events['start'], dayfirst=True)
events['end']=   pd.to_datetime(events['end'], dayfirst=True)
```

From this I derive a working copy and process it:

```
events_work= split_periods(events, 'start', 'end')
events_work=map_availability_of_start_day(events_work, df_cov['start_delta'], df_cov['end_delta'])
events_work[events_work['start'] <= events_work['end']]
# filter out all days with a negative period (sat and sun)
events_work.loc[events_work['start'] <= events_work['end'], ['start', 'end']]
```

The result is

```
Out[903]: 
                start                 end
0 2019-06-20 15:31:00 2019-06-20 18:00:00
1 2019-06-21 08:00:00 2019-06-21 15:00:00
4 2019-06-24 09:00:00 2019-06-24 10:45:00
```

Comment: Im going to try it! :) Thanks!